# Can you teleport into an antimagic field?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, teleportation, antimagic-field

Are you able to use teleportation magic, most notably [Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/) and [(Greater) Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/), to enter an active [Antimagic Field](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

[Antimagic Field](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Antimagic%20Field) states (emphasis mine):

> An antimagic field suppresses any spell or magical effect *used within, brought into, or cast into the area*, but does not dispel it. Time spent within an antimagic field counts against the suppressed spell's duration.

This means that Antimagic Field only suppresses a magical effect in these three cases:

1. The effect is used within the field (such as a caster attempting to cast a spell or use a supernatural ability).
2. The effect is brought into the field (such as a buff on a fighter that runs into the area).
3. The effect is cast into the field (such as a fireball being cast into the field).

Given that in our scenario, the wizard is not within the field when they cast the relevant spell, #1 does not apply. Given that the duration of the spells are instantaneous, #2 does not apply. This means that we only need to prove that #3 doesn't apply.

The rules for [Aiming a Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Aiming%20a%20Spell&Category=Spell%20Descriptions) state:

> You must make choices about whom a spell is to affect or where an effect is to originate, depending on a spell’s type. The next entry in a spell description [after range,] defines the spell’s target (or targets), its effect, or its area, as appropriate.

If we then look at the relevant portion of [Dimension Door](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dimension%20Door), it says:

> **Target** you and touched objects or other touched willing creatures

This means that dimension door is cast on the creatures, not into the Antimagic Field. Therefore, #3 does not apply. Since none of the statements for spell suppression are true, dimension door (and [teleport](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Teleport) which has a similar targeting line) allows you to teleport into an Antimagic Field.

---

If the reader is still doubtful of the above, there's no need to look anywhere else for more proof of how they interact. Antimagic Field also states:

> The effects of instantaneous conjurations are not affected by an antimagic field because the conjuration itself is no longer in effect, only its result.

Since Dimension Door and Teleport (plus variants) are instantaneous conjurations, they would work even if they did target the area of the Antimagic Field.

Comment: I... completely forgot that last line was in the wall of text that is AMF.

Answer (score 4):

Reviving this question to say: definitely no. The rules lawyering is impressive, but neglects to consider how the spell is described elsewhere in the game. The [rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/environment/the-planes/#Dead_Magic) for planes with the Dead Magic planar trait state:

> These planes have no magic at all. **A plane with the dead magic trait functions in all respects like an antimagic field spell**. Divination spells cannot detect subjects within a dead magic plane, **nor can a spellcaster use teleport or another spell to move in or out**. The only exception to the “no magic” rule is permanent planar portals, which still function normally.

This explicitly tells us that teleportation effects cannot be used into or out of Dead Magic planes and that Dead Magic planes function in all respects like an AMF. Meaning, teleportation effects cannot be used into or out of AMFs. Which is of course also the common-sense interpretation, but now you have the explicit rules to back it up.

Comment: I think this is interesting take on the matter. Can you expand on this to affirm or deny that a plane with dead magic doesn't have additional traits beyond those of an AMF, which would allow it to prohibit it being a teleportation destination while AMF would be a permissible destination?

Comment: This would suggest that planar portals could open inside of an AMF.

Comment: By extension would the "no magic" rule apply within an *antimagic field*, too? Because some magical effects like *wall of force* explicitly *do* function in an *antimagic field* (q.v. *DMG* 290, *PH* 200). I think that it's possible that the dead magic trait there may be describing *additional* effects of dead magic rather than clarifying how an *antimagic field* works.

Comment: A few lines of evidence. First, generally effects that function like something else with modification specify that. E.g. Charm Monster says "This spell functions like charm monster, except..." and Unliving Rage says "This spell functions as rage, except..." This is pretty explicitly saying that it functions *in all respects* as an AMF. That includes the respects of denying teleportation and divination. The only respect in which it is *not* like an AMF is that it allows permanent planar portals.

Comment: Second, I think it's pretty clear that when AMF says "The effects of instantaneous conjurations are not affected by an antimagic field because the conjuration itself is no longer in effect, only its result", it means that if you for example cast Cure Light Wounds on someone to heal them, the HP doesn't disappear if they walk into an AMF later. That doesn't mean you can cast CLW on someone currently in an AMF, though, as you can see from the wording - the "conjuration itself" would be blocked, the only reason it isn't blocked is because it doesn't exist anymore and only its result does.

Comment: Third, the structure of the paragraph. "These planes have no magic at all" - the 'no-magic rule'. Then an explanation of what this means mechanically: "A plane with the dead magic trait functions in all respects like an antimagic field spell." Then a list of relevant examples: "Divination spells cannot detect subjects within a dead magic plane, nor can a spellcaster use teleport or another spell to move in or out." Then an exception confirming we've been talking about the 'no-magic' rule: "The only exception to the “no magic” rule is permanent planar portals, which still function normally."

Comment: @Jason_c_o I don't think it would. The "no magic" rule is "A plane with the dead magic trait functions in all respects like an antimagic field spell." The only exception to this "no magic" rule is that permanent planar portals still function normally.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I read the "no magic" rule as being "A plane with the dead magic trait functions in all respects like an antimagic field spell." As for wall of force and the like, I'm not sure if those can be cast into AMFs. AMF says "Certain spells, such as wall of force, prismatic sphere, and prismatic wall, **remain unaffected** by antimagic field." To me, that sounds like they remain unaffected if an AMF moves onto them. But then again, the Antimagic section in the magic rules says "Wall of force, prismatic wall, and prismatic sphere are not affected by antimagic," so not sure.

Comment: I get where you're coming from. Still, it troubles me that this answer kind of depends on a missing (?) transition. (Seriously, we wouldn't be having this conversation if the second sentence began with *Further,* *In addition,* *Thus*, or *For example.*) Likewise, it troubles me that the second sentence includes *within a dead magic plane* specifically instead of referencing the aforementioned *antimagic field*. My troubles, though, needn't be yours: It's a good find.

Comment: By the way, welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]! Have fun, and thank you for helping strangers.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: The fact that it has to add a rule to prevent teleportation into dead magic planes means that you can normally do so with an AMF.